# Why does Html.DisplayFor show the model property name and not the property value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, razor, html-helper

I have the following Razor table column:

```
<td style="width: 300px;">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TendersReceived[i].Name)</td>
```

Yet the client side rendition of the column displays the model property *name*, i.e. the above displays `Name` in the Name column, instead of the actual name, the *value* of the `Name` property.

More info on the `TendersReceived` property:

```
public List<TenSubTenderersQualitySummaryItemViewmodel> TendersReceived { get; set; } = new List<TenSubTenderersQualitySummaryItemViewmodel>();

public class TenSubTenderersQualitySummaryItemViewmodel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Wq { get; set; }
    public decimal Threshold { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Qualify")]
    public bool DoesQualify { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Qualify")]
    public string DoesQualifyText => DoesQualify ? "YES" : "NO";
    public string Progress { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Staff Acceptability")]
    public string StaffAcceptability { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "POINTS RANKING")]
    public decimal PointsRanking { get; set; }
    public bool IsNrt { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsTechnical { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsManagement { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsQuality { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the `TendersReceived` class for us in your question please?

Comment: @NathanMiller I have done so.

Comment: @ProfK can you share any example of your expected output?

Comment: @ProfK Can u share your view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the

### [`DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_DisplayExtensions_DisplayFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___)

> Returns HTML markup for **each property in the object** that is represented by the Expression expression.

is incorrect. It is normally used for templating and one does not normally use `DisplayFor` for primitive types.

Using the above would try to render the property name as a label and then its value.

```
Name {value here}
```

if the value is null or empty string, you will only see the label.

Assuming the collection is a member of the model of the view, simply call the model's member

```
<td style="width: 300px;">@Model.TendersReceived[i].Name</td>
```